# Make many types of notification in same app in FCM by Functions which written by JavaScript in android/java

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I build an app which i need to add in it many types of notifications but i can't do it with myself because am have tiny knowledge about JS

I tried to deploy many functions by differnt body , title ..etc but it seems not able to deploy many functions in Firebase Functions

```
'use strict'


const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Noti/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context) =>
{
    const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;


    console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);


    if (!data.after.val()) 
    {
        console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
        return null;
    }

    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/user/${receiver_user_id}/token`).once('value');

    return DeviceToken.then(result => 
    {
        const token_id = result.val();

        const payload = 
        {
            notification:
            {
                title: "Open this notification now",
                body: `I have a problem in my car `,
                 icon: "default" ,
                sound: "default"




            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
        .then(response => 
            {
                console.log('This was a notification feature.');
            });
    });
});
```

thats all i have to describe my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy various functions, but you need to set different names for each one of them. The function name is after `exports.`, so you can have:

```
exports.sendNotification
exports.newMessageNotification
exports.newFollowerNotification
...
```

and each one of them will make what you wish them to do.